# Приватность проекта на GitHub

Tags: git, github

Я правильно понимаю, что, создавая проект, он будет доступен всем? Т.е. для создания приватного проекта нужно платить?

Comment: Да, вы все правильно понимаете. И даже если случайно там опубликуете что-нибудь не то, например, пароль, удалить окончательно уже не сможете.

Comment: удалить репозиторий с гитхаба можно

Comment: Тогда можете подсказать бесплатные аналоги? Нужно что-то для командной разработки проекта

Comment: Да, вот только все репозитории зеркалируются почти в реальном времени. Если хотите могу найти ссылку.
http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=41370

Comment: bitbucket.org идеально подходит, спасибо большое

Comment: @abalckin да, было бы интересно, если не сложно!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) можно создавать частные репозитории бесплатно в неограниченном количестве. Но бесплатно можно добавить максимум 5 других пользователей в эти репозитории.

Comment: Да. Скачал sourcetree и зарегистрировался в Bitbucket, создал там папку проекта, вроде как-то привязал его к локальной папке на моем ПК. Можно хорошую статью, как и что делать дальше? Куча вопросов. У меня не индексируются файлы (проект на unreal engine). Как добавить другого человека? Как сохранять проект (или он синхронизируется автоматически?)

Comment: Вам нужно почитать, как работать с GIT репозиториями вообще, как добавлять файлы в репозиторий, "пушить", "пуллить", "коммитить". [Книга по GIT][1]. Чтобы добавить человека в репозиторий, на странице репозитория на bitbucket есть кнопка "Send Invitation".
[1]:http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/

Comment: Пойду читать, спасибо

Comment: Что может значить ошибка error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413

Я пытаюсь залить свой проект на bitbucket

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489813/github-push-error-rpc-failed-result-22-http-code-413

Comment: Я немного не понимаю, где найти и поменять эти значения

Comment: Не понял Вас, вы пишете: "Я пытаюсь залить свой проект на bitbucket"
Какой командой? Приведите дословно.

Answer (score 4):

Да, вы все правильно понимаете. И даже если случайно там опубликуете что-нибудь не то, например, пароль, удалить окончательно уже не сможете. Все репозитории зеркалируются почти в реальном времени ([ссылка](http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=41370)).

Comment: @Fangog, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

С недавних пор на гитхабе тоже можно бесплатно создавать приватные репозитории. На странице создания репозитория нужно отметить соответствующую опцию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно и уже существующий публичный репозиторий [сделать приватным](https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-repository-visibility#making-a-public-repository-private).

Количество человек, которые могут вносить изменения в приватный репозиторий, ограничено тремя.